# How can I use a dependency in class scope?

Tags: c#

I want to use a dependency that I downloaded in the class scope. This code works:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;

namespace PrintFilesToConsole
{
    class Preprogram
    {
        public void Main2()
        {
            IEnumerable myDirs = System.IO.Directory.EnumerateDirectories("/Users/Eunice/Desktop");
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Preprogram preprogram = new Preprogram();
            preprogram.Main2();
        }
    }


}
```

but when I write

```
System.IO.Directory.EnumerateDirectories
("/Users/Eunice/Desktop");
```

outside of the function called

```
Main2
```

, into the scope of the class

```
 Preprogram
```

, the computer says that the function doesn't exist in the current context

unless I assign the return value to a variable, as in

```
IEnumerable myDirs = System.IO.Directory.EnumerateDirectories("/Users/Eunice/Desktop");
enter code here
```

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), right now your question is unclear.

Comment: You cannot run code in the class scope without assigning the result to a class member. [These are allowed class members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/#members)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's simplify your example to demonstrate where the problem lies.

---

We have the class `A` which contains the method `DoSomething`.

```
public class A
{
    public int DoSomething()
    {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

lets say it also contains the method `MakeStuff`, which calls the `DoStuff` method:

```
public class A
{
    public int DoSomething()
    {
        return 42;
    }

    public void MakeStuff()
    {
        int x = this.DoSomething();
        // We called the method DoSomething, which returns 42, and now x equals 42.
    }
}
```

what we did in `MakeStuff` is we **called** a method and **assigned the return value** to a **local variable**.

---

We could also put a **field** (or property) in the class `A`:

```
public class A
{
    private int y;

    ...
}
```

and we can even **assign a default value** to that field:

```
public class A
{
    private int y = 10;

    ...
}
```

but **the value doesn't have to be hardcoded**: we can also **use the return value of a function**, just as we did in the `MakeStuff` method when we assigned the return value to a local variable:

```
public class A
{
    private int y = this.DoSomething();

    // Now y equals 42, because DoSomething() returns 42.
    ...
}
```

but **we cannot call a function outside of a method if we discard the return value**, e.g. we cannot do this:

```
public class A
{
    this.DoSomething();

    // This will not compile!
}
```

---

I hope this simple example shows why you get the described error. I tried to keep it as simple as possible - yet if you don't understand parts of the answer or anything, please feel free to comment where you need help with and I will do my best to help you.

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Thomas. This solved my misunderstanding.

Comment: @Staxks good to hear that :)  If you feel the answer solved the problem, I would be happy if you mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older questions which still don't have answers.